# Regex: Best way to match all the entity types from México

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match the entity types from México.

It should match:

- S.A.
- SA
- S DE RL DE CV
- S. DE R.L. DE C.V.
- S.A. DE C.V.
- S.A.P.I DE C.V.
- SAPI DE CV
- SA DE CV
- S.A.B DE CV
- SA CV

I'm kinda stuck in the names that have "de Rablabla" and "de Caldsjsd" in the middle because my regex is matching the "de R" or "de C" and doesn't match "SA CV", "S.A.", "SA".

regex:

```
( s[^a-zA-Z]*((a[^a-zA-Z]*)|(a[^a-zA-Z]*p[^a-zA-Z]*i[^a-zA-Z]*)|(p[^a-zA-Z]*r[^a-zA-Z]*)|(a( +|\.)*b( +|\.)*)|(c( +|\.)*))*){0,}(de +((r[^a-zA-Z]*(l[^a-zA-Z]*)*)|(c[^a-zA-Z]*(v[^a-zA-Z]*)*))){1,}
```

Is it possible to this regex and am I doing this the right way?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a pattern with alternations allowing all the variations.

```
^S(?:\.?A\.?P\.?I|\.?(?:A\.?)?|\.A\.B)?(?:(?: DE R\.?L\.?)?(?: DE)? C\.?V\.?)?$
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `S` Match literally (is in all the examples)
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\.?A\.?P\.?I` Match A and P and I with optional dots
  - `|` Or
  - `\.?(?:A\.?)?` Match optional dot and optional A and dot
  - `|` Or
  - `\.A\.B` Match `A.B.`
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optinal
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?: DE R\.?L\.?)?` Optionally match  `DE RL` with optional dots for R and L
  - `(?: DE)?` Optionally match `DE`
  - `C\.?V\.?` Match CV with optional dots
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/exk3RW/1)

Comment: Great regex man. Just one more thing, I would like to match just "DE CV" too, how would I do that? I made it work somehow but I lost the regex. lol

Comment: @GuilhermeBordignon If there is just a single exception, you can use an alternation as currently all the valid strings begin with an `S` char. See https://regex101.com/r/id5EEs/1

Answer (score 0):

You could try it in regex101

My try:

```
(^S\.?\s?(A\.?\s?)?B?(P\.?I\.?)?(\sDE)?(\sR\.?L\.?)?(\sDE)?(\sC\.?V\.?)?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wkZVWw/1